# Netbeans maven project reverting to Java project on restart of netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, project

I am using Netbeans 8.2 (although this problem has been ongoing in previous versions). I can create a maven project, cut and past a previous one into that project, and then build the project and run it no problem.

When I shut down netbeans though, the maven project changes to a java project and the only fix I can find is to create a new maven project and repeat the cut and save.

There must be a better solution to this, if anyone has had a similar issue and fixed it please let me know!

Any help much appreciated,

Kris.

Answer (score 0):

you are probably copying some files that make the folder recognisable as a Java project. So likely have some build.xml in the base folder and/or some xml files in nbproject/ subfolder that are java project specific. Just copy only the source files you have.

Comment: That appears to have worked. I must have copied it over at some point and assumed I hadn't copied anything new across, and stupidly ticked off that box forever in my head.